# How this Clojure macro expansion works?

Tags: clojure

I am in the process of learning Clojure, through "Clojure for the Brave and True".

In macro lessons, I was trying the below macro,

```
(defmacro report
  [to-try]
  `(let [result# ~to-try]
     (if result#
       (println (quote ~to-try) "was successful:" result#)
       (println (quote ~to-try) "was not successful:" result#))))
```

And below are couple of my experiments with the macro and the respective outputs.

## 1

```
(map #(report %) ['(= 1 2) '(= 1 1)])
; p1__26622# was successful: (= 1 2)
; p1__26622# was successful: (= 1 1)
```

## 2

```
map #(report %) ['false 'true])
; p1__26612# was not successful: false
; p1__26612# was successful: true
```

And my questions are,

- Why in the former case the macro printed true for both values?
- In my understanding the second is exactly equivalent to the former. But why it gives a different result?

Comment: You can use `macroexpand-1` to see what happens when using a macro (what the code transforms to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why in the former case the macro printed true for both values?

Your `report` macro is receiving *quoted lists* as inputs, not expressions that can be evaluated to true/false. Any list is truthy, even if it contains an expression that would evaluate to false. This would give you the expected result:

```
(report (= 1 2)) ;; evaluates to false
```

> In my understanding the second is exactly equivalent to the former. But why it gives a different result?

It's not exactly equivalent because the first example is examining lists and the second is examining quoted booleans. Your second example evaluates `'false` as false because that's how `if` treats it:

```
(if 'false 0 1) => 1
```

Comment: `'false` yields `false`, just as `'1` yields `1`, because `false` is a literal, not because *that's how `if` treats it*.